# Echo command into cron without executing

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I've search for a solution but haven't found one as yet.

I've created a script which does a few things (installs applications, updates, makes directories, etc) and one of the lines are giving me problems.

I'm trying to echo a echo a command into crontab which has backticks for commands within it. Example, I want crontab to look like this:

```
* * * * * mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-space-util `df --output=source | grep /dev/ | /bin/awk '{print "--disk-path="$0}'
```

Instead of that though my script is first executing the command in backticks and then echoing into crontab something like this:

```
* * * * * mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-space-util --disk-path=/dev/xvda1
```

Currently the line which is supposed to echo this cron job in looks like this:

```
sudo sh -c "echo \* \* \* \* \* mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-space-util `df --output=source | grep /dev/ | /bin/awk '{print "--disk-path="$0}' | /usr/bin/tr '\n' ' '` >> /etc/crontab"
```

I've tried variations of echo cat and quotation marks but haven't come right yet.

I need to do this on both Ubuntu and Centos, not sure if the commands would differ.

Answer (score 0):

Can use ASCII code:

```
echo -e '\x60'
```

But actually I don't think that backticks are used nowadays anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For single quotes use `'\''`

```
sudo sh -c "echo '* * * * * mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-space-util \`df --output=source | grep /dev/ | /bin/awk '\''{print \"--disk-path=\"\$0}'\'' | /usr/bin/tr  '\''\n'\'' '\'' '\''\`' >> /tmp/crontab"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply escape it with: \
For example:

```
$ echo "* * * * * mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-space-util \`df --output=source | grep /dev/ | /bin/awk '{print \"--disk-path=\"\$0}'"
* * * * * mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-space-util `df --output=source | grep /dev/ | /bin/awk '{print "--disk-path="$0}'
```

Comment: can you please check if command work in this format "sudo sh -c echo ..."

Answer (score 0):

Whenver you have complex quoting issues, use a quoted heredoc:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat > /etc/crontab' << 'EOF'
* * * * * mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-space-util $(df --output=source | /bin/awk '/dev/ {print "--disk-path="$0}')
EOF
```

(And stop using backticks; $() notation is cleaner)
Although, as a side note, this is a bad idea. Much better to put this in a script and just invoke the script from cron.   That is, just put all the logic in mon-put-instance-data.pl, or write a simple wrapper.  And it also seems cleaner to write `df -- output=source | sed -n '/dev/s/^/--disk-path=/p'`